# Invalid parameter number issue using pdo in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have recently started doing mysql queries using pdo but I am getting the following error

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

My code is,

```
$conquery = $this->db->prepare("SELECT questions.quid,answers.catid,answers.ansid  
            FROM questions,answers where  questions.qtype  = ? and answers.userid = ? and (questions.quid = answers.quid)");

$conquery->execute(array('questions.qtype' => 'concern','answers.userid' =>$_SESSION['user_id']));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you misunderstood how parameters work.
THere are two ways to use parameters. And those ways cannot be used simultaneously.

## indexed parameters :

when you use indexed parameters, you use `?` inside your query.
THen to bind your parameters, you use a simple indexed array. In your cas you would write :

```
$conquery = $this->db->prepare("SELECT questions.quid,answers.catid,answers.ansid  
        FROM questions,answers where  questions.qtype  = ? and answers.userid = ? and (questions.quid = answers.quid)");

 $conquery->execute(array( 'concern',$_SESSION['user_id']))
```

## named paramameters :

When you use named parameters, you prepend a `:` to the parameter name (wich is right side og the equal sign) and then use a named array, in your case it would be :

```
$conquery = $this->db->prepare("SELECT questions.quid,answers.catid,answers.ansid  
        FROM questions,answers where  questions.qtype  = :qtype and answers.userid = :userid and (questions.quid = answers.quid)");

 $conquery->execute(array('qtype' => 'concern','userid' =>$_SESSION['user_id']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your parameters are not named in your prepared statement (you are using '?'), you should try this :

```
$conquery->execute(array('concern',$_SESSION['user_id']));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.I got a nice comparison of 2 methods described by artragis.